# Is There A Fraps Alternative That Records Different Audio Sources To Different Tracks

Tags: software-recommendation

I was wondering if there is a Fraps alternative that records audio from different sources to different tracks. unless fraps has this capability??

Comment: Hi and welcome to Video.SE. Right now the question is not very clear. Could you clarify (by using the edit function) what you mean by different audio sources? I would understand it in a regular audio recording setup, but as Fraps is used to record gameplay I'm not sure what is meant. Do you maybe mean the microphone and the game-audio?

Comment: Yes let me clarify. I have multiple sources, that being includes but sometimes is not limited to; my mic, teamspeak (communication with other), and the game of itself or whatever I am doing.

What I hope to do is to turn up/down individual sources at will, so as to not sacrifice the other audio sources.

Comment: I believe this will be difficult to do without specific hardware. Bandicam software separates different inputs (computer sounds, mic in, etc.) onto different tracks, however this isn't what you're looking for, so I won't make an answer.